# ERROR: for couchbase-db driver failed programming external connectivity

Tags: docker, couchbase

```
docker-compose up
Starting dev_couchbase-db_1
dev_mysql-db_1 is up-to-date

ERROR: for couchbase-db  driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dev_couchbase-db_1 (1fcc046cf53cac9faf47de38eb23469ab686a73a7cf6b1f55ea0d217f87fcab6): Bind for 0.0.0.0:11210 failed: port is already allocated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 63, in main
AttributeError: 'ProjectError' object has no attribute 'msg'
docker-compose returned -1
```

When i try to run those commands to start docker,  get those errors.

Then i do netstat:

```
:~/development/dfraud/docker/dev$ netstat -l
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
    tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN     
    tcp        0      0 localhost:63342         *:*                     LISTEN     
    tcp        0      0 vegan:domain            *:*                     LISTEN     
    tcp        0      0 *:37367                 *:*                     LISTEN     
    tcp        0      0 localhost:6942          *:*                     LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:28329              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:11210              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:3310               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:8091               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:8092               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:8093               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:40286              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

i see 11210 there. it seems empty.

and no others containers:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
86fa576a95f18       qq/baseline:hepsiburada   "/home/infoowl/instal"   3 days ago          Exited (1) 26 minutes ago                            dev_fraud-app_1
c113b94cf8817        mysql:5.7.11                   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   3 days ago          Up 16 minutes               0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp   dev_mysql-db_1
a3a39676f9f9c        couchbase/server               "/entrypoint.sh couch"   3 days ago          Exited (128) 11 hours ago                            dev_couchbase-db_1
b899a05f04ee7        hello-world                    "/hello"                 6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                                cranky_hypatia
bfa004e39fbf1        hello-world                    "/hello"                 6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                                modest_keller
37e6efc5b2ae9        mysql/mysql-server             "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   13 days ago         Exited (0) 9 days ago                                demo-mysql
cad1af1b49b10        c478557s729bb                   "sh -c 'cd /root/proj"   8 weeks ago         Exited (0) 3 weeks ago                               dev_turktelekom-app_1
9d32d908f8264        mysql:5.7.11                   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   8 weeks ago         Exited (0) 3 weeks ago                               dev_ttg-mysql-db_1
ff@ff:~/development/dfraud/docker/dev$
```

Whaat is problem?

Comment: i am on ubuntu not on machine

Answer (score 2):

This might be less related to couchbase-db, and more ro docker-compose.
See:

- [docker compose issue 3277](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277)
- [docker forum "Port mappings are not released"](https://forums.docker.com/t/port-mappings-are-not-released/10565/39)

It can happen when you don't remove VirtualBox while using Hyper-V (Windows) or Mac VM.

You also have this comment:

> I deleted all my custom networks, removed all my containers and then deleted `docker/network/files/local-kv.db` and restarted my machine.

Be warned:

> This issue is really two issues:
>
> 1. There's a confusing error message when a port is already in use by another application (e.g. Apache). That's been fixed in Docker 1.12.0 (it now explicitly says "port is already allocated").
> 2. After stopping containers, the ports they use are sometimes still mapped on localhost.

In your case, since you are on Ubuntu (no VM involved), *and* the message is "`port is already allocated`", you must have another service using that port.